# Do nothing lamda...

Tags: php, callback

```
$privilegeStrings = array_filter($privileges, function ($s) { return is_string($s); } );
```

Is there a better way to specify that I want just the string values in the given array?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do:

```
$privilegeStrings = array_filter($privileges, 'is_string');
```

`array_filter` passes every value of the array to the specified function. So you can just specify the function name and everything will be taken care of.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Ah.. didn't know you could pass the name of a function like that. Yuck!

Comment: @Billy ONeal - The name of a function is one acceptable form a [callback](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php) may take.